# Rest API to get Azure DevOps work item rollup columns/fields value

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

I can't seem to find any answers/questions related to fetching Azure DevOps rollup columns/fields value of a work item (eq. Epic). Basically I'm trying to see if we can get these rollup columns/fields value via REST API given a work item id. Also do they have any API to query the available custom/non-custom rollup columns/fields?

Azure DevOps Rollup documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/display-rollup?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process

[This is the rollup columns/fields I'm referring to:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7PvD.png)

I really appreciate the help/assistance. Also if someone can point me to a thread that may be more suitable to ask Azure DevOps related question please let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid that there is no such Rest API to get the Rollup columns.

Refer to the doc: [Prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/display-rollup?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process#prerequisites)

> Rollup column data is calculated from the Analytics service

The Rollup column is not a field of the work item itself. So you can’t directly use the Rest API to get it.

For a workaround, you can use Powershell to run Rest Apis ([Work Items - Get Work Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/get-work-item?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0), [Work Items - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)) to get the associated work item and the status or field value, and then perform further calculations to get the corresponding value.

On the other hand, You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion), which is our main forum for product suggestions.